# VBA function with particular excel sheet, not the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 particular excel sheet and a bunch of other excel workbooks with raw data.
That particular excel sheet works as a template for data analysis, so I copy-paste that sheet to a raw-data excel workbook to undertake analysis on that raw data.

Problem is that when I'm pasting the template sheet to the others, I need to change the reference every single time because the analysis is done referencing the sheet that contains row data. Also, sheet name is unique on
every workbook.

I tried the below VBA code but it's attached to the workbook rather than the template sheet itself, so I can't just create a copy of that sheet to a raw data excel workbook.

```
Function NxtShtNm() As String
    Application.Volatile
    NxtShtNm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Name
End Function
```

Could I get any advice on above?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the pasted template sheet/code to interact with sheets in the raw data workbook(s)?  Using  `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` might be what you need.  `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook that the VBA code is stored in.

Comment: Do you even need to fetch the name of the second sheet? Can't you just use the sheet index to begin with?